# Jest/React Testing Library : TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

```
test('OnClicking CSV download button it should show sucessMessage s', async () => {
    const closeModal = jest.fn();
    const refreshPage = jest.fn();
    render(
      <DownloadPops
        stationsLists={lists}
        closeModal={closeModal}
        refreshPage={refreshPage}
        code={'LAS'}
      />,
    );
    userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('csv-download-btn'));
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.getByTestId('success-message')).toHaveTextContent(
        'CSV downloaded successfully!',
      );
    });
  });
```

Here this test was worked before, but now after some times, it is showing this Typescript error don't know why. all types are properly assigned.

Comment: This is not a TypeScript error. This is a JavaScript runtime error that is thrown when running a Jest unit test. You unfortunately have not provided us with enough context to see where the problem is occurring. Can you please share the code that is causing this + format it for all the viewers. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)